# jQuery keydown() is being too hasty

Tags: jquery, hide, show, keydown

Essentially I have one visible element at all times and I'm using arrow keys to change the visibility to sibling elements.

`Arrow left` = Shows previous element to the visible one and then hides next element.

`Arrow right` = Shows next element to the visible one and then hides previous element.

**The problem is basically: Quickly pressing the arrow keys.**

In my jsfiddle the current visible one is 4 and if I quickly press `Arrow right` and `Arrow left` I end up with number 3 where as if you do it slowly ( waiting that all the animations finish up ) you end up with number 4 just like you should.

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/je2fZ/

What I want is to be able to press the arrow keys as quickly as humanly possible and end up showing the right number.

..and it's weird if you first press left and then right multiple times you end up showing all of the numbers... that isnt desired as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something other than `:visible` to mark the current element, as `:visible` will match for elements which are hid*ing* but aren't yet hidd*en*. **Demo using a class [here](http://jsfiddle.net/je2fZ/7/).**

Comment: I like that. It's quite simple. Not big fan of adding extra classes after I thought I was so clever for using `:visible` as the hook, but... you can't always win.

Comment: You could use `p:visible:not(:animated)` as the selector, which doesn't involve any classes, but then it will ignore any key presses during animations.

Answer (score 2):

This certainly won't be the cleanest solution but the first thing that came to mind was to keep track of the selected element in a variable:

```
$('p:nth-child(4)').show();
var current = 3;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        $("p").stop(true, true).hide(500);
        current = (current - 1 < 0) ? $("p").length - 1 : current - 1;
        $("p").eq(current).stop(true, true).show(500);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
        $("p").stop(true, true).hide(500);   
        current = (current + 1 == $("p").length) ? 0 : current + 1;      
        $("p").eq(current).stop(true, true).show(500);
     }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/je2fZ/6/). Note that this solution loops round once you reach the start/end and try to continue in the same direction. I don't know if that's what you're after, but it will be easy to modify.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution, I think, seems to be to use the `:animated` selector to check whether there's an animated element present and, if there is, return false. Or, rather, to test that there's *not* an animation in process and, only if there is no *current* animation, animate the elements:

```
$('p:nth-child(4)').show();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        if (!$('p:animated').length){
            $('p:visible').prev().stop(true, true).show(500).next().stop(true, true).hide(500);
        }
        return false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        if (!$('p:animated').length){
            $('p:visible').next().stop(true, true).show(500).prev().stop(true, true).hide(500);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/je2fZ/8/).

---

**Edited** to tidy up the above code, to reduce the nested `if`:

```
$('p:nth-child(4)').show();

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37 &&!$('p:animated').length){
        $('p:visible').prev().stop(true, true).show(500).next().stop(true, true).hide(500);
        return false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 39 && !$('p:animated').length){
        $('p:visible').next().stop(true, true).show(500).prev().stop(true, true).hide(500);
        return false;
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/je2fZ/9/).

References:

- [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/).